# Software or script to find source of recursion/loop in directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, symlink

As per title. I've noticed `du` and `find` commands can never finish but directory structure is very complex to search for loops etc by hand. I suspect there is one wrongly placed symlink there. Is there a tool to help find the source of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: `find -L -type l /start/here` will report broken links in GNU/Linux

From 'info find' in Linux:

> ‘-type’ reports the types of the files that symbolic links point to. This means that in combination with ‘-L’, ‘-type l’ will be true only for broken symbolic links.’